# Can I have my zombie dogs keep closer by?

Tags: diablo-iii

As a witch doctor, zombie dogs are without a doubt invaluable at the beginning of the game. The problem is that the zombie dogs lash out at anything they set their eyes on, often aggravating more monsters than I bargained for.

Is there any way to have the zombie dogs stay closer to me, or perhaps there is some way to make them less aggressive?

Comment: Have you tried keeping a few pieces of undead bacon in your pocket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real way to control your Zombie Dogs, sadly.  I find this to be one of the bigger disadvantages to this as a skill.  (The other being that they have *tiny* amounts of life)  The Gargantuan you unlock at level 19 is a bit better for this, since he tends to tank quite a bit better, which means you won't just be aggro'ing a bunch of enemies and giving them some fresh zombie dog meat to chew on as an appetizer for your... "shrunken head."

If you find you're aggro'ing more than you can handle at once, you might try throwing Grasp of the Dead and running away from the battle for a bit - enemies tend to have fairly short memories, and your dogs will teleport back to you if you get far enough away from them.

Comment: I suspected as much, how unfortunate.